# Get absolute path via CMD script of directory

Tags: batch-file, cmd

`script-being-invoked.cmd`:

```
REM This is my script file, it is being invoked from anywhere
REM Get absolute path to root directory
set astr=%~dp0
set substr1=\mq_1.7.6\interface\
set substr2=\
call set rootPath=%%astr:%substr1%=%substr2%%%
```

I'm trying to get the absolute directory path a few paths below from the file being invoked in the `interface` directory. The issue however is that the path in the code above changes. The version in `mq_1.7.6` could change. Is there anyway to get this value via cmd scripting? I would have done `\..\..` but this doesn't seem to work in Windows.

Comment: The simple solution could be `for %%I in ("%~dp0..\..") do set "rootPath=%%~fI"` if the batch file is stored in directory `C:\Temp\Test & Debug\mq_1.7.6\interface` and you want directory path `C:\Temp\Test & Debug`.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do that using the `~fi` expansion pattern. Unfortunately this can only be used (at least to my knowledge) in a `for` loop.

```
set "parentdir=%~dp0.."
for %%i in ("%parentdir%") do set "realparent=%%~fi"
echo "%parentdir%"
echo "%realparent%"
```

If the above is in a batch file located in `c:\foo\bar\mq_1.7.6\interface` the variable `realparent` will contain `c:\foo\bar\mq_1.7.6` and `parentdir` would contain `c:\foo\bar\mq_1.7.6\interface\...`

So the `for` loop essentially turns a relative path into an absolute path.

Comment: I'm sure you know about that, but just to mention, `~f` also works with [arguments](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)...

Answer (score 0):

Here's one method:

```
@pushd "%~dp0..\"
@echo %cd%
@popd
```

shorter one line:

```
@pushd "%~dp0..\" && echo %cd% && popd
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears from your question, that you're trying to retrieve the name of the scripts grandparent, in this case `mq_1.7.6`.

It is still a little unclear however, whether you want that in isolation, i.e. `mq_1.7.6`, or as an absolute path, e.g. `P:\ath\to\mq_1.7.6`

---

If the former is your intention then the following should suffice:

```bat
@For %%A In ("%~f0\..\..")Do @Echo(%%~nxA
```

If you need that as a variable then:

```bat
@For %%A In ("%~f0\..\..")Do @Set "Gp=%%~nxA"
```

If you're just trying to capture the version string from `mq_1.7.6`, in this case `1.7.6`, then a simple additional line may be all that is required:

```bat
@For %%A In ("%~f0\..\..")Do @Set "Gp=%%~nxA"
@Set "Gp=%Gp:*_=%"
```

---

If on the other hand you wanted the latter, i.e. the absolute path of the scripts grandparent, the the only real difference is in the metavariable expansion:

```bat
@For %%A In ("%~f0\..\..")Do @Echo(%%~fA
```

If you need that as a variable then:

```bat
@For %%A In ("%~f0\..\..")Do @Set "Gp=%%~fA"
```

---

If neither of my interpretations of your intent are correct, can you please provide an example of what you wanting to be returned, and whether you want that simply printing to the console, or saving as a variable etc.